# gulp task hangs after job done in nodejs

Tags: node.js, gulp

I defined the simple gulp task that can be run in terminal with `gulp load`. The purpose is to get number of users that does not have `location` property set.
However, after the number returned succesfully, the process hangs in terminal and I need to `ctrl-c` to stop it. Note, This is not a async call and uses `mongoose` plug-in to access DB.

```
gulp.task('load', function () {
    dbCall.getUserNumberWithoutLocation();
});

var getUserNumberWithoutLocation = function() {
    var query = User.find({ 'location': null });
    query.exec(function(err, users) {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            console.log(users[i].location);
        }
        console.log(users.length);
    })
};
```

Comment: "This is not a async call" - if you are talking about `User.find()`, of course is that an async call.

Comment: @Tomalak  ahh, you are right, my bonehead! Nevertheless, gulp does not terminate properly with async calls? Is this by design?

Comment: Of course it does, if you tell it that the call is finished. (gulp is highly asynchronous itself, after all). Look into the callback semantics of `gulp.task`. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support (Hint - you can write an answer your own question here on SO, this is a good opportunity for that.)

Comment: @Tomalak thank you very much! I have made `Finished task after xxxms` appearing. However, the prompt in terminal still does not return and I need to `ctrl-c` twice to go back to terminal input model.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the prompt still does not return after `gulp.task` done (which probably is my local machine issue), I put my code here. The `callback` function is passed into the inner `getUserNumberWithoutLocation` function, in which the it is called once `User.find` is completed.

```
gulp.task('load', ['style'], function (callback) {
    dbCall.getUserNumberWithoutLocation(callback);
});
exports.getUserNumberWithoutLocation = function(callback) {
    var query = User.find({'location': null});
    query.exec(function(err, users) {
        console.log(users.length);
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback();
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  I have a gulp task that runs other tasks and then finishes.